# How to stop server-side timer on user disconnect? (node.js/socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have some server-side timer, that worked on socket.io:

```
// timer function
    function startTimer() {
         var countdown = 15000;
         var serverInterval = setInterval(function () {
            countdown -= 1000;
            socket.in(room_name).emit('timer', {countdown: countdown});
         }, 1000);
     }

// timer usage      
     socket.on("start timer", function() {
         startTimer()
     }
```

But when user disconnecting, I want to `clearInterval` and stop that timer:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      clearInterval(serverInterval);
});
```

What causes the error "serverInterval is not defined".

How to make variable global in current document, but not global in whole project and stop my server-side timer on user disconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function to store the context of serverInterval like

```
var ServerInterval = (function () {
    var serverInterval;
    return {
            set: function (obj) {
            serverInterval = obj;
            },
            get : function() {
                return serverInterval;
            }
    };

})();

// timer function
    function startTimer() {
         var countdown = 15000;
         ServerInterval.set(setInterval(function () {
            countdown -= 1000;
            socket.in(room_name).emit('timer', {countdown: countdown});
         }, 1000));
     }

// timer usage      
     socket.on("start timer", function() {
         startTimer()
     }

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      clearInterval(ServerInterval.get());
});
```

and then call it using a getter/ setter

Answer (score -1):

Make the variable global by defining it in the global scope, instead of `var serverInterval = ...` should be `global.serverInterval = ...`.

Or, better, attach the variable to the socket object: `socket.serverInterval = ...`, and in the disconnection: `clearInterval(socket.serverInterval)`.

Comment: This is not a great advice, the code runs in association of a user, and your server normally deals with more than one user - global variables are totally inappropriate for this.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about making the variable visible, which requires a global scope. Final implementation should certainly be more elaborated.

Comment: It doesn't require a global scope at all, it requires a _proper_ scope.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll attach the variable to the socket object itself.